# Convert array to map

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert a array of unique ids to a flat map of theses

```
const arr = [ { user1: 'val' }, { user2: 'val' } ]
```

and I want to convert to

```
{ user1: 'val', user2: 'val' }
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `arr.reduce((map, elem) => ({...map, ...elem }));
`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [`array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
arr.reduce((obj, val) => ({...obj, ...val}))
```

Comment: How does that work?

Comment: I've added a link to the documentation please read it https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: but basically, it reduces an array to a single value, doing a operation.

Comment: I know what reduce does, how does using spread operators on the collector and value turn into a flat map?

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out; it's spreading out it's children and maintains the list by including the collector. Nice.